# In R, using results of rle (Run Length Encoding) including named row and column headers

Tags: r, list, export-to-csv, nested-lists, export-to-text

I have a large matrix containing companies as row names, months as column names and data for each of the elements. Test data below:

```
testmatrix<-matrix(c(1,0,0,0,10,5,5,5,5,5,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1),nrow=4,ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(testmatrix)<-c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May")
rownames(testmatrix)<-c("Company1","Company2","Company3","Company4")
progression<-apply(testmatrix,1,rle)
progression
```

The progression object is the output of the rle function applied over each of the rows of the matrix. The result is a list with 2 elements that are both of class 'rle'. I would like to:

1. Understand how to output (in R) a 4x3 (row by column) matrix of Company1 as follows:

[image]

Hence I'm struggling to understand how to deal with the output provided by `progression`

2. Export `progression` to excel for further analysis (preferably in the format in (1) above (including column and row headers (in the list output they're referred to as: attr(*,"names")).

Your assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks TLM for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not particularly elegant but this does the job:

```
format_rle <- function(rle, rn){
  l <- list(rle$lengths,
    names(rle$lengths),
    rle$values,
    names(rle$values))
  m <- as.matrix(do.call(rbind, l))
  colnames(m) <- NULL
  rownames(m) <- rep(rn, nrow(m))
  m
}
```

Try `format_rle(progression[[1]], "foo")` to get the idea:

```
[,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
foo "1"   "3"   "1"  
foo "Feb" "May" ""   
foo "1"   "0"   "10" 
foo "Jan" "Apr" "May"
```

Then we apply this function to all elements in progression and save the result to individual csv files named according to the names in progression. You should have `a bunch of .csv` files in your working directory (`getwd()` to print it).

```
for (i in seq_along(progression))
  write.csv(format_rle(progression[[i]], names(progression)[i]),
            file=paste0(names(progression[i]), ".csv"))
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Vincent, I should call you Mon homme in place of Bonhomme. Excellent answer. I actually should have been more specific with my question as I also wanted a full excel output of all of it (I have 2000+ companies) so creating 2000 csv files isn't practical. So here's my adjusted code for getting everything in 1 file:`for (i in seq_along(progression))
  write.table(format_rle(progression[[i]], names(progression)[i]),
              file="append.csv",append=T,sep=",",col.names=F)`. That's for everyone else; I'm sure if I had expressed it correctly you would have provided it too. Thanks again